# Repeating a call to a function to produce current time difference in Swift playground

Tags: swift, function, repeat

In a swift playground, why does this code not update. I am trying to get this to output the exact time (in the future to have a countdown) but I can't get the current time to update, **it just repeats the same time difference several times.**

```
// initialize the date formatter and set the style
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

// get the date time String from the date object
let currentDate = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime)

let dateMakerFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateMakerFormatter.calendar = userCalendar
dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy, hh:mm:ss a"
let endTime = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString("01/08/16, 11:00:00 PM")
let startTime = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString(currentDate)
let hourMinuteComponents: NSCalendarUnit = [.Month,.Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second]
let timeDifference = userCalendar.components(
    hourMinuteComponents,
    fromDate: startTime!,
    toDate: endTime!,
    options: [])
timeDifference.month
timeDifference.day
timeDifference.hour
timeDifference.minute
timeDifference.second
func printTimeDifference() {
    print("\(timeDifference.month) Months, \(timeDifference.day) Days, \(timeDifference.minute) minutes, \(timeDifference.second) seconds")
}

var done = 0
//printTimeDifference()
var counter:Int = 0

while done != 10 {
    sleep(1)
    printTimeDifference()
    done++
}
```

I may have put too much code in this, but the major part would be the loop. **How come when I call printTimeDifference() it doesn't print the current difference to the second, it just prints what the current date was at (I'm assuming) the first call.** To the best of my knowledge the variables live and die with the function, and each time I call the function it should be recreating the variables, i.e getting the actual current difference in time. **My speculation is this could have something to do with Strong and Weak links** but I am relatively new to swift and have done more in C. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's because `timeDifference` is computed only once, before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you write:

> To the best of my knowledge the variables live and die with the
>   function, and each time I call the function it should be recreating
>   the variables

This is true, but only if the variable is created within the function. In your case you do not create a new variable inside the function `printTimeDifference` and you are using already created `timeDifference` which was once assigned a value. Naturally after the function returns, this variable will not be deleted, as created outside the function. And when you next time to call this function it is used the same variable with the same value. It is one single variable `timeDifference`

You get the desired effect if the transfer of the creation of all necessary variables into the function `printTimeDifference` like:

```
func printTimeDifference() {
    // Here your code with all variables creation
    ...
    // with this variable you need to print
    let timeDifference = userCalendar.components(
        hourMinuteComponents,
        fromDate: startTime!,
        toDate: endTime!,
        options: [])
    print("\(timeDifference.month) Months, \(timeDifference.day) Days, \(timeDifference.minute) minutes, \(timeDifference.second) seconds")
}
```